# PredectionIO via vagrant : pio-start-all: command not found

Tags: linux, predictionio

I've been struggling for weeks just trying to install PredictionIO.
Today I came across a new "easy" method for installing via vagrant: https://www.sitepoint.com/predictionio-bootstrapping-a-movie-recommendation-app/

When I type `$ vagrant up`
it gives the following output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20170925-16688-9a1tte.sh
==> default: PredictionIO already installed. Skip installation. 


**==> **default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 32: pio-start-all: command not** found**



==> default: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
==> default: PredictionIO VM is up!
==> default: You could run 'pio status' inside VM ('vagrant ssh' to VM first) to confirm if PredictionIO is ready.
==> default: IMPORTANT: You still have to start the eventserver manually (inside VM):
==> default: Run: 'pio eventserver --ip 0.0.0.0'
==> default:
```

Kindly help, I am not an expert of linux & vagrant

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/772898/vagrant-shell-provision-command-not-found

Comment: This is not a programming question. Should be closed.